# how to plot column vector data along y-axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this row/column vector.

```
grades = [90, 100, 80, 70, 75, 88, 98, 78, 86, 95, 100, 92, 29, 50];
plot(grades);
```

In MATLAB, I want to plot grade values along x-axis and indices (1-14) along y-axis. By deafult, indices are plotted along x-axis. How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grades = [90, 100, 80, 70, 75, 88, 98, 78, 86, 95, 100, 92, 29, 50];
figure;
plot(1:length(grades),grades); % Indices along X
figure;
plot(grades,1:length(grades)); % Indices along Y
```

Comment: still no change in output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot data in Matlab. You have to define data sets for all the axis which you are interested in.

In your case, define x-axis data and y-axis data.

So for example your Y axis data would be

```
grades = [90  100 80 70  75 88 98 78 86 95 100 92 29 50];
```

for your x data you can use the following.

```
X = 1:14;
```

then you have the following plot command

```
plot(x,grades)
```